# How to detect the line where an error was originated and not where the error was executed. PHP

Tags: php, class, error-handling

I have a class file (for example: myclass.class.php) that I include and use in many files, every time I don't use the class properly PHP will give me back an error showing the filename and the line where the error happened, the problem is that I always get the line inside myclass.class.php and not the actual line in the file where the error was originated.

I know that I can overwrite the default error handler, and I created this function:

```
function customError($errno, $errstr, $errFile, $errLine){
   $error =  "- [".date("Y-m-d, H:i:s")."] Error on page ".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]." from file $errFile on line $errLine: Error #[$errno] $errstr, ";
   $error.="Previous page: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].", IP:".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
}

set_error_handler("customError");
```

But so far none of the variables `($errno, $errstr, $errFile, $errLine)` give me the error line in the file generated, I always get the `$errLine` of the class file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Example (the numbers are the line numbers:

inside class_file.php:

```
33 public function getRows($result){
34    return mysql_num_rows($result)
35 }
```

inside another_file.php

```
101 $rows = $myclass->getRows('this is not a mysql result');
```

the error would something like:

**error in class_file.php, mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource; line 34**

And I want to get the line 101 inside another_file.php which is actually where the error was originated. Like:

**error in another_file.php line 101, executed in class_file.php: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource; line 34**

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code where the error is "claiming" to be? So that we might ensure that the error is in fact not occurring there?

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: The [`set_error_handler` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) says you are using `$errLine` correctly: "_The fourth parameter is optional, errline, which contains the line number the error was raised at, as an integer._" Show how you include the files that you believe are causing the error. Perhaps the error is in the include statement.

Comment: Hi @Tom and George I added an example to my question, it is not exaclty my code but that is irrelevant, it works for any case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to add more robust error handling so that if the class is used incorrectly it lets you know. Of course, this implies that you know the extent of exceptions you'll need to handle. Implementing a better error handler is a start. You can trace back up the call stack by using [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

The first element of the backtrace is always the current function/method, followed by the caller of that function/method, and so on up the chain. Inside an error handler the first element is the error handler function. With that in mind and based on your sample code you could do the following:

```
function customError($errno, $errstr, $errFile, $errLine){
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $error =  "- [".date("Y-m-d, H:i:s")."] Error on page ".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]." from file ".$backtrace[2]['file']." on line ".$backtrace[2]['line'].": Error #[$errno] $errstr, ";
    $error.="Previous page: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].", IP:".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
    die $error;
}
```

Of course, that is somewhat of a contrived example base on your sample code. What you'd really want to do is walk the backtrace array and report all the relevant info. But this should get you started.

If you want to know everything you can get from the backtrace just run `echo '<pre>' , print_r(debug_backtrace(),TRUE) , '</pre>';` from within your error handler.

Comment: Could you give me more feedback? , I am not quite understanding the documentation from PHP, thanks.

Comment: @EddyXP I updated the answer with an example based on your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the additional code that was asked for, you are in fact causing the error within your class.

Your Code:

```
public function getRows($result){
    return mysql_num_rows($result)
}
```

If the user supplies a result that is not a resource, your class will blindly use it. You need to determine whether or not this is a valid resource before using it or simply allow it to fail.

For example:

```
public function getRows($result){
    if (!$result || !is_resource($result)) {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error(
            'getRows expects valid mysql resource' .
            ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
            ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
            E_USER_NOTICE);
        return false;
    }

    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

Or if your error handler respects the mute:

```
public function getRows($result) {
    $rows = @mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows !== FALSE) {
        return $rows;
    }
    else {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error(
            'getRows expects valid mysql resource' .
            ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
            ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
            E_USER_NOTICE);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could look at setting up xdebug. Then you wouldn't have to worry about this as much. http://xdebug.org/